# gulp error process teminated with code 1

Tags: gulp, karma-jasmine

Hello I am trying to run jasmine unit tests using karma in VS. I have a var simple gulp task that should just work. I am getting the error `Process terminated with code 1.`.

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done()).start();
});
```

this gets the error above.

when I add `funtion(){done();}` 
I get the below error:

> Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0
>   secs) Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.008
>   secs / 0 secs) [10:11:37] Finished 'test' after 2.27 s

and when i do just `done` I get the following error.

> at formatError
>   (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
>       at Gulp. (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
>       at C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
>       at finish (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
>       at cb (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
>       at removeAllListeners (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:380:7)
>       at Server. (C:\Users\James.Tays\Desktop\UnitTestingAngular\Tests\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:391:9)
>       at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at emitCloseNT (net.js:1523:8)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:463:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:385:17)

Can someone please tell me why I am getting different errors, and how can I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I have Figured out the error, this came from the `karma.conf.js` basePath was wrong.

the documention shows `basePath: '../...',` so i copied that exactly and saw that it should be `basePath:'../Path_TO_TEST_PROJECT_HERE'`.

I thought that may help others.